# “Перекрестье” и “перекрестие” — два разных слова или формы одного и того же?

Tags: значение-слов

“Перекрестье” и “перекрестие” — это формы одного и того же слова, как “страданье” и “страдание”, или два разных слова, как “воскресенье” и “воскресение”?

Вроде бы более правильно звучит *перекрестье дорог* (а не “перекрестие”), но *перекрестие прицела* (не “перекрестье”). С другой стороны, в ряде случаев кажется, что слова абсолютно взаимозаменяемы.

Comment: @ enkryptor,в словаре только перекрет***ь***е прицила.

Comment: @Серж https://lopatin.academic.ru/95504/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5 ?

Comment: Крестообразная сетка прицельного приспособления. ***П. прицела***. Поймать цель в п. 3. Большой толковый словарь русского языка ( на Грамоте.ру).

Comment: Это одно и то же значение?

Comment: @Серж это и есть суть вопроса.

Comment: Вы не поняли: перекрестие (в оптике) и перектье прицела то же самое?

Comment: @Серж Мне кажется да, но я не могу гарантировать. Это не имеет значения в контексте вопроса. "Перекрестие прицела" — просто один конкретный пример, который может быть и неправильным. Вопрос в том, возможны ли вообще ситуации, в которых эти слова не взаимозаменяемы.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, это одно слово: нейтральное редуцированное -ье, книжное на -ие.

ПЕРЕКРЕ́СТЬЕ -я; мн. род. -тий, дат. -тьям; ср.

1. То, что состоит из пересекающихся линий, планок и т.п. Стальные перекрестья моста.
2. Место перекрещивания чего-л. Ремонт на п.путей. // Крестообразная сетка прицельного приспособления. П. прицела. Поймать цель в п.
3. То, что имеет форму креста. П. брёвен. П. стропил.

Энциклопедический словарь. 2009.https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/es/125772/%D0

Что касается терминов, их сегодня чаще употребляют в книжной форме (курсор - перекрестие), на -ие, но слово всё равно одно - от слова крест. Если кто-то скажет перекрестье - это разговорный вариант, только и всего.